# Suppose there exists a injection from $S$ to $N$, and similarly one from $T$ to $N$. Then there exists an injection g from $S×T \to \mathbb{N^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose there exists a injection from $S$ to $\mathbb N$, and similarly one from $T$ to $\mathbb N$.

Then there exists an injection g from $S×T \to \mathbb{N^2}$.

How do i explicitely find such injection$

Thanks

Comment: Is $N = \mathbb{N}$ or is it a different set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h: S \to \mathbb N$ and $g: T \to \mathbb N$ be injections.
Then take $f: S  \times T \to \mathbb N^2$, where $f(s,t)=(h(s),g(t))$.

Then, $f$ is well defined. Suppose that $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$. See if you can show that $(a,b)=(c,d)$

Here is something I consider neat:

Take $k(s,t)=2^{h(s)} \cdot 3^{g(t)}$, an injection $k: S \times T \to \mathbb N$.

Comment: If i write all elements of cartesian product as given here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable ....will the map $(s_i,t_j) \to (i+1,j+1)$ work

Comment: Sure, but it requires that you first give the elements of $S,T$ an order, or endow it with some $\leq$ relation, something like this.

Comment: The map to $(i,j)$ would work just as well.

Comment: I think not because the first element will not get mapped as 0 is not in set N.....i am talking about enumeration given in link

Comment: Well, I suppose if you want to start your indexing at $0$... Why not just enumerate $S=\{s_1,...\}$. Either way, there are some technicalities here. To prove that there is a countable enumeration, you first have to use the fact that  you have an injection, so $| S| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$, and then enumerate (however you want), proving existence. It is easier to use the functions directly.

Comment: Yes thanks indeed

Answer (score 1):

Let the first injection be $f_S: S \to \mathbb{N}$ and the second be $f_T : T \to \mathbb{N}$. Consider $g: S \times T \to \mathbb{N}^2$ as,

$$g((s,t)) = (f_S(s), f_T(t)).$$